# Bug in production - A static file is corrupted for a specific user?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, static-files

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I just couldn't find a better description of this bug.

One of our users had problems with the site, and saw a Syntax Error in one of the Javascript files in the dev console. When they opened it, they saw it was corrupted:

[image: The corrupted file]

They sent me the contents of the file (went directly to the URL and saved with Ctrl+S) and when I opened it with Sublime it seemed to be nulled-out (the binary is all zeros). This only happened to them and it doesn't seem to go away, even after a full restart. I initially thought it was just a corrupted response and Chrome cached the file, but even with Shift+F5 they are still getting the problem.

The user runs Chrome 64.0.3282.186

the server is running django on AWS.

Edit: The user says they have no Chrome extensions installed.

Edit II: They tried from Microsoft Edge and it works.

Comment: Maybe the user is behind some proxy that mangles with the file?

Comment: He says he is not.

Comment: Is that a static file or is it dynamically generated?

Comment: static, as the title says.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Sorry. I'm a bit out of options :(

Comment: He tried from a different browser and it works. Any ideas?

Comment: I would insist on them checking the settings for proxies and stuff, since it's possible that the other browser is using different settings and ignores the proxy set on Chrome. Otherwise I have no idea :(

Comment: i'd try creating a new chrome profile (I never experienced this kind of issue before)